# Stop page break between title and contents

Tags: table-of-contents, titles, titlesec

I am using the article class in LaTeX, and I want a page break between sections, so I added the following to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
```

However, I don't want a page break between the title and contents page. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
\title{Linear State Space Control Theory}
\date{June 4, 2015}
\author{texasflood}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section{Introduction}
Hello
\section{State space description}
\end{document}
```

I tried adding `\nopagebreak[4]` in between `\maketitle` and `\tableofcontents` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\title{Linear State Space Control Theory}
\date{June 4, 2015}
\author{texasflood}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
\section{Introduction}
Hello
\section{State space description}
\end{document}
```